# jQuery* Calculating multiple values individually from other tables

Tags: jquery, html, css

A row in table will intercept the number being written in any graph and post the total of all numbers with the id name 'qty1'. Now the solution is currently found at: https://accountingbgs.000webhostapp.com/ so if you want a live version -> Go there.

But what I need help with is the face that when I create a new table, and want to add numbers in the column with 'qty1' labeled in there, it will add it up ONLY for that table.

```js
function addup(x){
  var sum = 0;
  $('.qty1').each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $(x).val(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <span class="td">
      <input onclick="addup(this)" class="qty1" type="number" id="amount1" name="amount1" style="text-align:center;"/>
    </span>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: you are updating the number that user just entered, this can result in an infinite loop. Where is the live version? Additionally you have an extra + sign in your code here: sum += +$(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addup(x){
            var sum = 0;
            $('.qty1').each(function(){

                sum += Number($(this).val());
                
            });
           
            $(x).val(sum);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="td"><input onclick="addup(this)" class="qty1" type="number" id="amount1" name="amount1" style="text-align:center;"/></span></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="td"><input onclick="addup(this)" class="qty1" type="number" id="amount2" name="amount1" style="text-align:center;"/></span></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="td"><input onclick="addup(this)" class="qty1" type="number" id="amount3" name="amount1" style="text-align:center;"/></span></td>
<tr>
</table>
```